# Why am I getting gson Exception: Expecting object found?

Tags: java, json, exception, google-cloud-messaging, gson

I am using the GSON API 1.7.1 sometimes having following error. Is there a bug for this version? Do I need to upgrade the current version 2.x.x

```
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Expecting object found: "<!DOCTYPE"
        at com.google.gson.JsonObjectDeserializationVisitor.visitFieldUsingCustomHandler(JsonObjectDeserializationVisitor.java:100)
        at com.google.gson.ReflectingFieldNavigator.visitFieldsReflectively(ReflectingFieldNavigator.java:63)
        at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.accept(ObjectNavigator.java:120)
        at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.fromJsonPrimitive(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:85)
        at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.deserialize(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:56)
```

**The server** is google push notification server GCM,

**Here is my client code.**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse webResponse=  
                resource.header("Authorization", authorizationKey).
                header("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
                post(com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.class, payloadStr);
String responsePayload = webResponse.getEntity(String.class);
GcmResponse response = gson.fromJson(responsePayload, GcmResponse.class);   ===>>> Exception point
```

Comment: It will be better if you post the code that throws this exception.

Comment: Your server is returning a non-JSON response, it has nothing to do with the version you're using.

Comment: @GPrathour I have editted the question,

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE` looks like you might be getting an html error page instead of your expected JSON result.

Comment: I think so, but why GCM send such error sometimes and when I retry to send request all things work well.

Comment: It would be better if you can share response you are getting from the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a bug for this version?

No. Looks like your server is returning a non-JSON response or you're passing wrong parameters, this has nothing to do with the version you're using.

Try to check if the server is working as expected and is returning a JSON.

Comment: when I try to resent same query , I get success response. This problem occurs at 1% of all messages that I have send.

Comment: @mmc18 then 1% of the time you're getting a wrong response. Catch the exception and print to the log the response you're getting.

Comment: I have added the exception into my question before, do you need more?

Answer (score 1):

`<!DOCTYPE` is not valid Json; your server sometimes sends the wrong messages to your client. Since your client works 99% of the time, the **problem is clearly in the server somehow**, not the client.

However, since you've only provided us information here from the client side, there isn't enough for us to fix the problem. The best thing to do would be to attempt to capture the complete error message, then use searches or post a **different question** "Why does my android-scm server send messages that begin with `<!DOCTYPE` when they should be Json?"

To capture this complete errant message, I would do:

```
if(response.startsWith("<!DOCTYPE")) {
    someLoggingMethod(response);`
} else {
    // process the response
```

Comment: you are right, I have modified the code then waiting for the problem occured again.

Comment: I have captured the error log after debug logging enabled. here is the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29936241/gcm-502-http-response